# como hacer que mi pagina web se vea bien en todos los dispositivos

Tags: css, web

estaba tratando hacer que mi pagina web se vea bien en mi teléfono pero cuando le aplique las modificaciones de lugar en mi celular se veía bien pero en la computadora mal me pueden ayudar por favor

Comment: ¿Podrías concretar con código? Es difícil saber qué está ocurriendo sin verlo.

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y por lo mismo puede quedar cerrada, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Todo lo controlas con la propiedad CSS `media query`:

```css
/* Estilo por defecto en Mobile First */
body{
  background-color: black;
}

/* Estilos actualizados para pantallas desde 500px de ancho en adelante */
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  body{
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Te recomiendo siempre trabajar un diseño web con la metodología *Mobile First*, es decir, que por defecto tu sitio se vea bien para pantallas pequeñas y con el uso de `@media (min-width)` vas añadiendo estilos para pantallas más grandes de forma progresiva. Esto es una buena práctica porque te permite trabajar con herencia de CSS y tienes más control sobre su comportamiento.

Por favor, igualmente estudia la documentación, buena suerte!
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: No le presté atención, tienes razón. Lo tendré presente en el futuro.